# How to convert xs:dateTime to xs:string in xslt

Tags: xml, datetime, xslt, xpath, saxon

We are trying to convert date-Time from GMT to EST so that we following this approach.

1. we are getting date-time without timezone in String and then appending time zone to it.
2. After appending timezone, converting DateTime to EST from GMT.
3. adjust-dateTime-to-timezone will return date time in EST with
   timezone.
4. Now, we want to return EST date-time without timezone as String from this template.

**Here is my xsl -**

```
<xsl:template name="convertGMTToEST">
          <xsl:param name="gmtDateTime" />
            <xsl:variable name="gmtDateTimeWithTimeZone" select="concat($gmtDateTime,'+00:00')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="estDateTime" select="adjust-dateTime-to- 
           timezone(xs:dateTime($gmtDateTimeWithTimeZone),xs:dayTimeDuration('-PT5H'))"/>
            
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($estDateTime, '-')"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

**Expected Output-**
we want to return EST dateTime without timezone in xs:String.
How can we convert xs:dateTime to xs:string before doing substring-before as first argument of fn:substring-before() is xs: string;
**Note-** we are using xslt 2.0 processor.

Comment: Check the `format-dateTime` function in your favourite XPath function reference, for instance https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#date-time-examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are over-complicating this. The difference between GMT and EST is a constant 5 hours. Why don't you simply subtract 5 hours from the given dateTime and be done? For example:

**XML**

```
<input>
    <string>2020-01-01T20:45:15</string>
    <string>2020-01-01T04:15:30</string>
</input>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/input">
   <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="string">
            <string>
                <xsl:value-of select="xs:dateTime(.) - xs:dayTimeDuration('PT5H')"/>
            </string>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>    
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <string>2020-01-01T15:45:15</string>
   <string>2019-12-31T23:15:30</string>
</output>
```

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to the question "How can we convert xs:dateTime to xs:string" is: use the `string()` function. But as @michael.hor257k points out, I think you're making things unnecessarily complicated.